# Linux- Permission denied?

Tags: linux, permissions, bash, unix, shell

I'm installing Neo4j server as a linux service, but when I install it, I get the following message:

```
/sbin/insserv: Permission denied
```

What is this? What should I do? I'm running everything with `sudo`.

**Update - Scenario**:

1. I had installed it properly the first time, but then I moved the neo4j-directory to a different location.
2. The neo4j-service was not recognized now.
3. I removed the neo4j-service manually by removing from `/etc/init.d` and then running `update-rc.d -f neo4j-service remove`
4. When I re-install it said `/sbin/insserv` no such directory, so I googled and did this:

   `ln -s /usr/lib/insserv/insserv /sbin/insserv`
5. Now when I re-install it - it says  `/sbin/insserv: Permission denied`

Using **Ubuntu**.

**etc/sudoers**:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

**Permissions on neo4j install script:**

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 username username  15K Feb 27 09:38 neo4j`

**UPDATE 2**:

When I do a `ls -lah` on `/sbin`:

`lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     16 May 15 20:29 insserv -> /usr/lib/insserv`

and a `ls -lah` on `/usr/lib`:

`drwxr-xr-x   2 root root      4.0K Feb 14 03:37 insserv`

Comment: Give steps that you have done cause that error.

Comment: What OS (I assume Ubuntu), what part of the install throws this error, what commands did you run?

Comment: Try `man insserv`. What does your `/etc/sudoers` contain?

Comment: @Gnouc updated question

Comment: @NickW Updated with the commands.

Comment: What does `/sbin/insserv` point to?  Is it a symlink, but you moved where it needs to look?

Comment: What are the permissions on neo4j-service (`ls -lah`)?

Comment: @TomO'Connor `-rwxr-xr-x 1 username username 15K Feb 27 09:38 neo4j`

Comment: @vgoff I'm a little newbie. Please explain what you mean.

Comment: Can you `ls -lah` on /sbin/insserv too ?

Comment: If you view the permissions of that file, you would see a `l` instead of a dash.  It might look similar to the permissions you have shown for neo4j, except it would be 'lrwxr-xr-x' perhaps.  The 'l' on the left indicating that it is a link to a file (that may not exist if you moved it.)

Comment: @TomO'Connor updated

Comment: I suspect insserv isn't the problem here.

Comment: If this is Ubuntu, please remember that it uses upstart, not "common" init or dependency-based boot, as Debian does. There's a reason the insserv package doesn't bundle /sbin/insserv in Ubuntu, while it does in Debian. Your best bet would be to add a upstart configuration file in /etc/init for the neo4j service, instead of trying to use a script in init.d. I know this is not the answer to your question, but I hope to address the real problem instead :-)

Comment: Is selinux enabled?  Run [sestatus](http://serverfault.com/questions/617682/unable-to-re-enable-selinux) to find out.

Answer (score 1):

rsuarez makes some good points about your init/upstart configuration.  However, it is not clear if you are getting the same error when running the `insserv` program as root manually.  There are two things you can do to debug the `insserv` permissions directly:

1. See if the `/sbin/insserv` command gives the same error when running from a command line manually
2. If you get the same permission denied from #1, try to run it with `strace` to see what file or permissions it is failing on.  If #1 does not give you permission denied, then follow the rsuarez and @TomO'Connor guidance to look at the potential upstart or Neo4j problems because it is probably not directly related to the `/sbin/insserv` binary.

Comment: And in addition: "which" insserv to avoid the binary existing in multiple path locations leaving you wondering about the right permissions on the binary you would expected to be executed rather then the one which actually is tried to be executed by your command.